# Can alpha transparency fill or stroke style be set separately from RGB in Canvas HTML5?

Tags: html, canvas, alpha

In Canvas/HTML5, I know you can use RGBA to set color and alpha transparency for fillStyle or strokeStyle.  You can also use just RGB to set color with no alpha channel.  is there a way you can change the alpha value of an item without also supplying the color.

My example would be wanting to change the fillStyle or strokeStyle above a canvas section whose color was random or no longer known.  Is there a way to change the alpha through another attribute or by passing nothing to the color (e.g. ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(,,,alphaValue)';)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways.

First, the `globalAlpha` attribute of the context.

As you ask in the title, it will allow transparency to be set independently of fill or stroke.

You could then use the `getImageData` on a point to find out the color and save that info, clear that area with `clearRect`, set `globalAlpha`, and then redraw that area with the color you saved.

Of course, you don't need `globalAlpha` at all. You could also do the above and instead of setting global alpha, just modify the alpha of the color that you saved.

If you want to make a large, complex area of canvas more transparent, then you will want to change the globalAlpha and then *draw the canvas onto itself* using drawImage.

[Here's an example of that.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gtvv6/) I draw two rectangles, then make a rectangular area between them more transparent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function to extract the RGB values from whatever is set for the style you are interested in, and then set it with the desired alpha:

```
var rgb = hexToRgb(canvasCtx.fillStyle);
canvasCtx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + rgb["r"] + "," +rgb["g"] + "," + rgb["b"] + ",0.2)";
```

You can use an hexToRgb function like this one, taken from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb):

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
        return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });

    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
```